# Formatting Pascal's Triangle in Java

Tags: java

I've recently been teaching myself Java and I made a piece of code to produce Pascal's triangle. However, I can't get it to print out properly in a triangle. I can't figure out how to take into account numbers with multiple digits. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Pas{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    pas(20);
}

public static void pas(int rows){

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        String spaces = "";
        int counter = (rows + 30)/2 - i;
        for(int f = counter; f > 0; f --){
            spaces += " ";

        }

        System.out.print(spaces);
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print( ncr(i, j) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static long ncr(int n, int r){
    return fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n - r));
}

public static long fact(int n){
    long ans = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        ans *= i;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Please keep in mind I'm a complete beginner and have never had any actual instruction. Everything I know is from the internet and messing around in Eclipse.

Comment: @Adi He/she is worried about the formatting of the console output.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you're having is with spacing.

You are using always one space after a number, which is a problem because one number can be of length 1 - i.e: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - and another can be of length 5 - i.e. 31824. Because of that your triangle is wider on the right side.
To change that you have to reserve equal space for all your numbers - so if your biggest number is 184756 then for every number you print you have to reserve place for 6 digits and 1 empty space after them.

Also your initial spacing is not related to the number of rows, which in general can generate problems (if you would like to make triangle bigger than 30 - your current constant).

So there are two places where I would suggest changes:
First is this **(1)**:

```
int counter = (rows + 30)/2 - i;
```

Here 30 is a constant that works for your 20 dimention triangle, but it's not elegant and won't work for bigger triangles. So I would suggest something like this **(2)**:

```
int counter = (maxNumberLength*(numberOfRows - i))/2;
```

`maxNumberLength` is the maximum length the numbers in your triangle can get. How to calculate it? I'have estimated like that **(3)**:

```
Math.pow(2d, numberOfRows.doubleValue());
```

This power will always be bigger than the biggest value in the triangle, but not by much. You can do it differently - it's first that came to my mind.

So back to (2)... the numberOfRows is the number of rows in the triangle. You substract `i` before multiplying to get the initial space `maximumNumberLength/2` smaller in every row (so that it has a left slope).

The second thing that I would suggest changing is this:

```
System.out.print( ncr(i, j) + " ");
```

That's the most important part as you always add 1 space. If maximum number length is 6, then you should add 6 spaces after `1`, 5 spaces after `20` and so on. Thats why I suggest creating a method that would return you the number of spaces you need **(4)**:

```
private String spaces(final Long number, final int maxNumberLength)
{
    StringBuilder spaces = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i<maxNumberLength - number.toString().length(); i++)
    {
        spaces.append(" ");
    }
    return spaces.toString();
}
```

In **(4)** you take number as first param (that's the number that is to be followed by spaces) and `maxNumberLength` from **(3)**. This way all of your numbers would take the same amount of spaces in the output. I build the spaces with StringBuilder which is more effective for String concatenation.

So that's it - two changes and it should work.
I attach my full code so if you need you can test it:

```
public class TraingleTest 
{
    private final BufferedReader input;
    private Integer numberOfRows;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        new TraingleTest(input).run();
    }

    private TraingleTest(final BufferedReader input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    private void run()
    {
        boolean validNumber = false;

        System.out.print("Please enter number of rows for Pascals Triangle: ");
        do
        {
            String usersInput = readUserInput();
            validNumber = validateInput(usersInput);
        } while (!validNumber);

        makeTriangle();
    }

    private String readUserInput()
    {
        try
        {
            return input.readLine();
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Error while reading input. Please try one more time: ");
            return "";
        }
    }

    private boolean validateInput(final String input)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (inputValue > 2 && inputValue < 22)
            {
                numberOfRows = inputValue;
                return true;
            }

            System.out.print("Value must be an integer between 3 and 21. Please insert valid number: ");
            return false;
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Error while parsing input. Please insert valid number: ");
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void makeTriangle()
    {
        int maxNumberLength = Double.valueOf(Math.pow(2d, numberOfRows.doubleValue())).toString().length();

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
            String spaces = "";
            int counter = (maxNumberLength*(numberOfRows - i))/2;
            for(int f = counter; f > 0; f --)
            {
                spaces += " ";
            }

            System.out.print(spaces);
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                long number = ncr(i, j);
                System.out.print(number + spaces(number, maxNumberLength));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private String spaces(final Long number, final int maxNumberLength)
    {
        StringBuilder spaces = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i<maxNumberLength - number.toString().length(); i++)
        {
            spaces.append(" ");
        }
        return spaces.toString();
    }

    public long ncr(int n, int r)
    {
        return fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n - r));
    }

    public long fact(int n)
    {
        long ans = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            ans *= i;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// I have not inputted the rows you can just give an input statement and input no of rows

```java
public class PascalTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            int number = 1;
            System.out.format("%"+(rows-i)*2+"s","");
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                 System.out.format("%4d",number);
                 number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will help you

```
int rows = 10;


for(int i =0;i<rows;i++) {
    int number = 1;
    System.out.format("%"+(rows-i)*2+"s","");
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
         System.out.format("%4d",number);
         number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for 20. It's not about giving the solution but about explaining why OP code doesn't work.

Comment: his code not make perfect triangle because there are no unique space between numbers .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to is to decree that every number you output will use a set number of characters, and to add extra blanks if necessary when outputting each number.  For example, you can decide that each number will take 4 characters (if all the numbers are 9999 or less--actually, with Pascal's triangle with 20 rows, you'll need at least 5 characters).  Then you'll need to adjust the number of spaces you print out in each row of the triangle.

To convert a number to a 4-character string where the number is pushed over to the right of the 4-character "box", and you add blanks on the left if necessary, use `String.format`:

```
String output = String.format("%4d", number);
```

If you want the number to be at the left of the "box",

```
String output = String.format("%-4d", number);
```

If you want the number to be centered in the "box", this is harder.  Here's a method that will pad a string on both sides with blanks, making the padding as close to equal on both sides as possible:

```
public static String center(int desiredLength, String input) {
    if (input.length() >= desiredLength) {
        return input;
    }
    int leftPadding = (desiredLength - input.length()) / 2;
    int rightPadding = desiredLength - input.length() - leftPadding;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < leftPadding; i++) {
         result.append(' ');
    }
    result.append(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < rightPadding; i++) {
         result.append(' ');
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

and then you could say

```
System.out.print(center(4, Integer.toString(number)));
```

or, if `number` is a `long`,

```
System.out.print(center(4, Long.toString(number)));
```

(P.S. Instead of `StringBuilder`, you could declare `result` to be a `String` and use things like `result += " "` like you did in your original question.  That would work just as well, except maybe a few nanoseconds slower.)

Answer (score -1):

```
package myjavapractice;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pascaltriangle 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int[][] pascal=new int[n][];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pascal[i]=new int[i+1];
    }
    pascal[0][0]=pascal[1][0]=pascal[1][1]=1;
    for(int j=2;j<n;j++) {
        pascal[j]=getNextRow(pascal[j]);
    }
    //print
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pascal[k]));
    }
}


static int[] getNextRow(int[] p)
    {
        int[] current = new int[p.length];//row
        System.out.println("length "+p.length);
        current[0]=current[current.length-1]=1;//colmn

        for(int m=1;m<current.length-1;m++)
        {
        current[m]=p[m]+p[m-1]; 
        System.out.println("pof m is"+p[m]);
        }``
        return current;
    }
}
```